# iOS First Application "self.userName = textField.text". When to use self

Tags: ios, self, accessor, notation

Here is a code snippet from Apple's "Your First iOS Application" document.

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

self.userName = textField.text;

NSString *nameString = self.userName;
if ([nameString length] == 0) {
    nameString = @"World";
}
NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
label.text = greeting;
[greeting release];
}
```

I understand that self.username calls the synthesized set method (important since it has a copy flag).

Why is textField.text and label.text not self.textField.text and self.label.text.

Are the two equivalent?
Is the self unnecessary since the dot notation is there already which would already access the get methods?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: `textField.text` is equivalent to `self.textField.text` in this case, because the synthesised getter simply returns the text field. Presumably Apple have gone for terseness because they want the code to be readable. I'd favour your approach though: with properties, it's a good habit to stick to the accessor methods, in case you ever want to customise them.

Note that the property is a separate entity from the internal variable. Apple's style is to give them both the same name, but some programmers like to separate the two concepts by giving internal variables underscore prefixes. In that case, `_textField.text` would give the same result here as `self.textField.text`. But only the second would be accessing your class's generated getter method for the text field - the first is exercising its right as a piece of class-internal code to access the internal variable directly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Assuming the class to which textField is an object of, has appropriately synthesized the getter and setter methods, would _textField.text run the get method?  If not, would it then be inaccessible if _textField's text instance variable is set to private?

Comment: Note that in at least [some cases](http://tinyurl.com/4yxm7tf), Apple reserves the underscore prefix for its own use. You may be better off using using an underscore suffix instead, e.g. use `textField_` instead of `_textField`.

Comment: @Ben: yes, if the `_textField` object has a `text` property, it should provide a getter (whether synthesised or not), and the dot notation will call it. If it didn't provide one and the instance variable was private, then the data would indeed be inaccessible to objects of other classes.

Answer (score 2):

No, they're not the same. In the code you provided, `textField.text` translates to `[textField text]`, i.e. gets the `text` property of the object pointed to by the `textField` ivar. `self.textField.text`, on the other hand, translates to `[[self textField] text]`, i.e. calls the current object's `textField` accessor, and calls the `text` accessor of the result.

The end result should usually be the same. It would be somewhat strange to have both an ivar and a property named `textField` and to have the property return something other than the ivar.

> Are the two equivalent? Is the self
>   unnecessary since the dot notation is
>   there already which would already
>   access the get methods?

As explained above, the results are similar, but the meaning is different. Using the accessor (i.e. `self.textField.text`) is the preferred style, but prefixing everything with `self.` can seem a little tedious too. One possible remedy if you're going to use a property repeatedly is to call the property accessor once and keep the result in a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Both are the same. You may use self.label.text or label.text (whichever) as both point to the same object.

Answer (score -1):

You said it yourself, they are equivalent since `self.label` and `label` will point to the same object.

I would prefer to use the `self.label` version for more clarity but that's entirely a coding practice.

It's important to point out that there's a performance hit when your use the `self.label` since you're calling a method (which is not free). However, in most read-world cases, the performance hit is not noticeable (just good to know).