# Accessor invocation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, setter, accessor

What is the difference between:

```
self.ivar;
self->ivar;
ivar;
```

Way of accessing `ivar`'s in objective C.

When will the setter be invoked?

Comment: Possible duplciate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259946/objective-c-message-syntax-vs-dot-syntax-whats-the-difference

Comment: It would be nice to accept some answers before asking an other one. Also make some research, this question has been asked plenty of times : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188954/ios-first-application-self-username-textfield-text-question-when-to-use-sel/6189059#6189059 and documentation is quite good about that http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17

Comment: The setter won't be invoked at all -- you're not setting anything in any of those statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self->ivar` and `ivar` access the instance variable directly. The accessor method is not called.

`foo = self.ivar` will call the `[self ivar]` accessor method (or the `@property`'s `getter=` method if you specify it that way)

`self.ivar = foo;` wil call the `[self setIvar:foo]` access method (or the `@property`'s `setter=` method).

Answer (score 1):

In non-ARC environments, the both `self->ivar`, and `ivar` include no Objective-C calls, and instead set and get scalars from memory.  The dot syntax, (e.g. `self.ivar`, or `[self setIvar:]`) makes an Objective-C call to a setter/getter method that can handle memory management, etc. Apple's @property includes @synthesize, which writes these method implementations for you.

In ARC environments, both properties and manually assigning an ivar include some memory management logic. It may even be that, in optimized ARC environments, the use of @property simply uses ARCs built-in logic, rather than making Objective-C calls whenever possible.